# Get enum item type from enum type

Tags: typescript

Given the following `enum`:

```
enum Style {
    Compact,
    Switch,
    Default
}
```

how can I get the type `Style` from the type `typeof Style`? For example, I would like to use it with my enum-cast function, which takes in an enum definition and a number as its arguments, and returns the number "as an item" of the specified enum if that number is defined by the specified enum:

```
function castToEnum<T>(_enum: T, value: number): T {
    if (_enum.hasOwnProperty(value.toString())) {
        return value as any; // 'value' is defined by '_enum'.
    } else {
        throw new TypeError(`enum does not define value '${value}'.`);
    }
}
```

This is how I would like it to be working:

```
var style1 = castToEnum(Style, 0); // Ok, style1 === Style.Compact
var style2 = castToEnum(Style, 1); // Ok, style2 === Style.Switch
var style3 = castToEnum(Style, 2); // Ok, style3 === Style.Default
var style4 = castToEnum(Style, 3); // TypeError
```

Here, I would like `styleX` to be of type `Style`. However, since the generic type parameter `T` on `castToEnum` is detected as having the type of `typeof Style`, `styleX` will be of that type as well.

[Demo on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Style%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Compact%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Switch%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Default%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20castToEnum%3CT%3E(_enum%3A%20T%2C%20value%3A%20number)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(_enum.hasOwnProperty(value.toString()))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%20as%20any%3B%20%2F%2F%20'value'%20is%20defined%20by%20'_enum'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20TypeError(%60enum%20does%20not%20define%20value%20'%24%7Bvalue%7D'.%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20style%20%3D%20castToEnum(Style%2C%201)%3B%0D%0A)

How could I accomplish this? I tried using `typeof`, but it does not work with generic type parameters, since those are types already.

**How can I make this type conversion, from an enum type to an enum *item* type?**

---

**Edit:**

With non-abstract classes, it is possible to get the instance type from a class type with the following function signature:

```
function createInstance<T>(_class: new () => T): T {
    return new _class();
}
```

This will effectively take an argument of type `typeof T`, and return a value of type `T`, in case of classes with a parameterless constructor signature. This approach does not work for enums, unfortunately.

Comment: Right, enums don't behave the same way as classes do, and so there's no way (as far as I know) to state that you receive an enum "class" and return an instance of it. See my answer to how you can still make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive the enum as `any`:

```
function castToEnum<T>(_enum: any, ordinal: number): T {
    if (_enum.hasOwnProperty(ordinal)) {
        return _enum[ordinal];
    } else {
        throw new TypeError(`enum does not define value '${ ordinal }'.`);
    }
}

console.log(castToEnum(Style, 0)); // Compact
console.log(castToEnum(Style, 1)); // Switch
console.log(castToEnum(Style, 2)); // Default
console.log(castToEnum(Style, 3)); // TypeError
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Style%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Compact%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Switch%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Default%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20castToEnum%3CT%3E(_enum%3A%20any%2C%20ordinal%3A%20number)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(_enum.hasOwnProperty(ordinal))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20_enum%5Bordinal%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20TypeError(%60enum%20does%20not%20define%20value%20'%24%7B%20ordinal%20%7D'.%60)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(castToEnum(Style%2C%200))%3B%20%2F%2F%20Compact%0D%0Aconsole.log(castToEnum(Style%2C%201))%3B%20%2F%2F%20Switch%0D%0Aconsole.log(castToEnum(Style%2C%202))%3B%20%2F%2F%20Default%0D%0Aconsole.log(castToEnum(Style%2C%203))%3B%20%2F%2F%20TypeError))

---

#### Edit

This should work as you want it to:

```
function castToEnum(_enum: any, ordinal: number): number {
    if (_enum[ordinal]) {
        return ordinal;
    } else {
        throw new TypeError(`enum does not define value '${ ordinal }'.`);
    }
}

var style: Style = castToEnum(Style, 1);
console.log(style === Style.Switch);
console.log(castToEnum(Style, 3)); // TypeError
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Style%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Compact%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Switch%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Default%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20castToEnum(_enum%3A%20any%2C%20ordinal%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(_enum%5Bordinal%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20ordinal%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20TypeError(%60enum%20does%20not%20define%20value%20'%24%7B%20ordinal%20%7D'.%60)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20style%3A%20Style%20%3D%20castToEnum(Style%2C%201)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(style%20%3D%3D%3D%20Style.Switch)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(castToEnum(Style%2C%203))%3B%20%2F%2F%20TypeError))

The function needs to return a `number` otherwise this:

```
style === Style.Switch
```

Will be false.
And it works with type safety.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will make the function lose type-safety if I don't explicitly specify the generic type parameter. Consider `var style: Style = castToEnum(Style, 1)`. Also, with this example, TS will give the compile error *"Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Style'."*

Comment: Of course, if I use it as `var style: Style = castToEnum<Style>(Style, 1)` it will work as expected, but I'd wish to avoid having to explicitly specify the generic type parameter.

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: Yes, but this requires an explicit type-assertion once again. If I do `var style = castToEnum(Style, 1)` then `style` will be of type `number` instead of type `Style`. I was hoping I could embed this type-assertion into the function signature somehow, without having to essentially define the same type twice.

Comment: True, but you probably don't have a way around that. That's because enums return `Style.Compact` as a `number` and `Style[0]` as a `string`. Only with type assertion will you be able to get it as `Style`. I'm afraid that you probably can not do it without the assertion.